# Contextually grey out panel element in python 2.8

Tags: python, panel

I have a panel with split column.  In the 2nd row is 3 boolean variables.
I want to grey out the 2nd and 3rd option by default.
I want the 2nd to be changeable if 1st is true, and 3rd to be changeable if both 1 and two are true.
I've read something about "poll()" but not how to actually use it, or set conditions.
Physics should only be enablable if singleMesh, and destructable only if physics enabled.

```
    # Create two columns, by using a split layout.
    split = layout.split()

    # First column
    col = split.column()
    col.label(text="Building Size:")
    col.prop(bpy.context.scene.user_vars, 'buildingHeight')
    col.prop(bpy.context.scene.user_vars, 'buildingWidth')
    col.prop(bpy.context.scene.user_vars, 'buildingDepth')

    # Second column, aligned
    col = split.column()
    col.label(text="Dynamics:")
    col.prop(bpy.context.scene.user_vars, 'singleMesh')
    col.prop(bpy.context.scene.user_vars, 'enablePhysics')
    col.prop(bpy.context.scene.user_vars, 'destructable_Building')

#EDIT This is what the specific solution to my example looks like.
col = split.column()
col.label(text="Dynamics:")
col.prop(vars, 'singleMesh')
sub = col.row()
sub.enabled = vars.singleMesh
sub.prop(vars, 'enablePhysics')
sub = col.row()
sub.enabled = vars.enablePhysics
sub.prop(vars, 'destructable_Building')
```

Comment: `sub = col.row()` would suffice.

Comment: Ah, Thanks very much.  You've been exceptionally helpful.  I'm getting a massive amount accomplished due to your very timely help.  ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Set `UILayout.enabled`**

> [`UILayout.enabled`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.enabled)
>
> When false, this (sub)layout is grayed out

*eg* enable subrow in a row if context object has rigid body settings

```
row = self.layout.row()
sub = row.row()
sub.enabled = context.object.rigidbody is not None
sub.prop(foo, "bar")
```

Note that `context` is passed as an argument to draw methods.  Get out of the, IMO, bad habit of always addressing from `bpy` *ie* if in a draw method `def draw(self, context):` use `context` in method code not `bpy.context`.

The poll method works on a per [`Panel`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html#simple-object-panel) or `Menu` or `Operator` class *et al* case.  The following will ensure `FooPanel` only draws when there is a context object.

```
class FooPanel(bpy.types.Panel):

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None
```

panels that don't poll don't show. Operators are disabled if in layout but don't poll.  It is important to have a  poll method in most cases.

Re versions, both layout enabled and poll method are avalable in all versions >= 2.50.

Comment: From my understanding, the first enables/disables an entire row, which isn't quite what I'm looking for.
I want to grey out just 1 property of a column.
I don't understand, at all, how to add/alter what you wrote to fit the code I already have.
Nor do I understand "Get out of the, IMO, bad habit of always addressing from bpy"
Sorry, I'm a C# guy, python looks bassackwards to me.  ~_~

Comment: Ah, I think you misunderstand.
I have a column.  I want the 2nd button in 2nd column to be greyed out until first button in that column is selected. And the 3rd button should be greyed out until both the first and 2nd button are checked.
"context.object.rigidbody" isn't valid in this context.

Comment: Thanks, not quite right, but close enough to where I was able to alter it to get it to work.  Thanks a TON!  You've helped me on several problems already.  ^_^