# Disable button when another button has been enabled

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, panel

So what I need is when **Eyes Follow Cam** is *False* then **Head Follow cam** and **Influence** is disabled(grayed out)
and when **Eyes Follow Cam** is *True* then **Head Follow cam** and **Influence** is enabled

[image: this is my panel]

Here is the code for for the necessary parts:

```
import bpy 

from bpy.props import BoolProperty

bpy.types.Scene.EyesFollowCamera = BoolProperty(
    name="Eyes Follow Cam?",
        description="Makes the Eyes to follow the camera",
        default = False)
bpy.types.Scene.FollowCamera = BoolProperty(
    name="Head Follow Cam?",
        description="Makes the head and spine to follow the camera",
        default= False)

from bpy.props import FloatProperty

bpy.types.Scene.FollowInfluence = FloatProperty(
    name="Influence",
        description="Infuence of Head following eyes",step = 10,min=0, max=1,precision =3,
                default = 0.6)

class Blah_settings(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Settings"
    bl_category = "IDK"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
   

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        sce = context.scene
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(sce, "EyesFollowCamera", icon = "HIDE_OFF") 
        row.prop(sce, "FollowCamera", icon = "USER")
        row.prop(sce, "FollowInfluence")
      
classes = (Blah_settings, )


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Do I achieve it through a if statement? if so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contextually grey out panel element in python 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160883/contextually-grey-out-panel-element-in-python-2-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign any `bool` to `UILayout.enabled` (layout element): https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=uilayout#bpy.types.UILayout.enabled

> When false, this (sub)layout is grayed out

[image]

Quick demo using the 'Use Nodes' property (`bool`) in the *World Panel*. If enabled the other element (can be anything) gets greyed out.

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the World properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "WORLD_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "world"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
        
        # Layoutelement.enabled = any bool
        row.enabled = not context.world.use_nodes

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[How do I get the opposite (negation) of a Boolean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030831/how-do-i-get-the-opposite-negation-of-a-boolean-in-python)

Comment: @YunethAlwis https://www.codepile.net/pile/deJ8GGWo same thing...